# Why is my overlayfs command not working?

Tags: overlayfs

The commands below should be creating a root overlay, such that any modifications to root will appear in /tmp/upper

However as you can see it does not appear to be working.  Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

I am following the syntax here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt

thanks

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-48:~$ sudo su
root@ip-10-0-0-48:/home/ubuntu# cd /tmp
root@ip-10-0-0-48:/tmp# mkdir upper
root@ip-10-0-0-48:/tmp# mkdir workdir
root@ip-10-0-0-48:/tmp# mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=/,upperdir=/tmp/upper,workdir=/tmp/workdir  /
root@ip-10-0-0-48:/tmp# touch /floob
root@ip-10-0-0-48:/tmp# ls /
bin  boot  dev  etc  floob  home  initrd.img  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  snap  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var  vmlinuz  x
root@ip-10-0-0-48:/tmp# ls /tmp/upper/
root@ip-10-0-0-48:/tmp#
```

Comment: You are asking the same question as [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/316018/133107). Where did you get the idea that mounting to `/` will succeed? Certainly not from the referenced document. You can mount elsewhere and `chroot`.

Comment: @techraf You can certainly mount an overlayfs filesystem to `/`. It's a pretty common scenario.

Comment: But I'm not sure if you can do it directly. You may have to mount it on a subdirectory and chroot into it. At least that's what overlayroot does.

Comment: @Gilles Ok, so what happens to current processes, open files? They suddenly switch to the overlay-mounted root? Regarding your second comment, you are repeating my words ("month elsewhere"). I am confused now.

Comment: @techraf Open files keep using the lower filesystem, no matter how you do it. That's why an overlay root is usually established from by the initramfs.

Comment: @Gilles I'm not getting English. I asked OP for the source and then wrote "You can mount elsewhere and chroot" and you responded with "You may have to mount it on a subdirectory and chroot into it." These two sentences are exactly the same (aren't they?). What was your intention?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just created a bunch of overlays, one for each of the top level directories that I was interested in.

The point of the exercise was to isolate changes made during package installation and this seems to do it well enough for the most part.

```
#/bin/bash
array=( lib home opt bin boot var etc usr srv lib64 root sbin  )
mkdir -p /ovl
cd /ovl
rm -rf /ovl/overlay
rm -rf /ovl/workdir
mkdir -p /ovl/overlay
mkdir -p /ovl/workdir

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
  mkdir -p /ovl/overlay/${i}
  mkdir -p /ovl/workdir/${i}
  mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/${i},upperdir=/ovl/overlay/${i},workdir=/ovl/workdir/${i} /${i}
done
```